# How to enable auto-reloading in expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

Ive been trying to make a simple app in react native using expo, till yesterday when i saved my app.js file it automatically refreshed the app running on my phone but today i tried running the app it doesnt reload when i save the file after making changes and im also getting this [new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0iT3.png) till yesterday all was working fine i dont know what happened today. when i click reload on the reload button it reloads but it was much easier when it was automatically refreshing everytime i save.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like you have enabled Debug mode and disabled Fast Refresh. Open the developer menu: https://docs.expo.io/workflow/debugging/#developer-menu

> iOS Device: Shake the device a little bit, or touch 3 fingers to the
> screen.
>
> iOS Simulator: Hit Ctrl-Cmd-Z on a Mac in the emulator to simulate the
> shake gesture, or press Cmd+D.
>
> Android Device: Shake the device vertically a little bit, or run adb
> shell input keyevent 82 in your terminal window if your device is
> connected via USB.
>
> Android Emulator: Either hit Cmd+M, or run adb shell input keyevent 82
> in your terminal window.

Then `Enable Fast Refresh`.

You might want to also disable Debug Mode by selecting `Stop Remote Debugging` (this will improve performance and get rid of that localhost window you posted)

Comment: Hmm, my iPad doesn't show me an option for `Enable Fast Refresh` or `Stop Remote Debugging`. Is it just too old? (iPad Air, iOS 12.5.5 which is the highest version it can run)  (My developer menu only has 3 options, Reload (which I'm using because it won't auto-refresh!), Copy link and Go to Home)

Comment: Ok, so it seems to occasionally work, and then after a while stop working. When it's working, the Expo snacks page shows it at Devices on the bottom bar. But when it's not working, Devices is 0. (But I can still manually reload it!)

Comment: It is important to note that you must have first launch the Expo Go app on your android as well as run expo start before this snack bar can show up when you shake the device Vertically.